# Concrete5 Stuck in Edit Mode

Tags: publish, edit, mode, concrete5

I am using Concrete5 for developing a website and I cannot get out of the Edit Mode. Whenever I click on "Exit Edit Mode" the entire screen darkens and I cannot click on the publishing options.  Also, the hover area for the content areas is pushed down about 30px.  If anyone has seen this happen before, or knows how to fix this please let me know.

http://tk.hostfury.net/test2/img/messeduppage.jpg

Answer (score 1):

There is a jQuery file called bgStretcher.js that was built into the design. I commented the file out and now I can publish pages again. There must be something in that file that is messing with ezCMS.  If I find out the exact cause, I will report it here.

Comment: ezCMS or Concrete5? It's very possible that there was a javascript conflict with that file. Did you try FireBug to see if any errors were reported?

Comment: It turned out to be a javascript error, because ezCMS also calls a bgStretcher.js as well, so the original programmer had to go back and rename the bgStretcher instances & the bgStretcher file.